# Как добавить свой шрифт для программы в Sublime Text3

Tags: консоль, sublime-text, командная-строка

Программа считывает с файла текст на русском языке, и выводит в консоль. Компилирую программу через, консоль выводит "Кракозябры".В интернете пишут шрифт должен быть "Lucida Console" для консоли.Изменила шрифт консоли.Посмотрела в настройках Sublime text 3->File->Save with Encoding данного шрифта нет в списке. По умолчанию шрифт в Sublime text 3 стоит "Consolas". как в этот самый  Save with Encoding добавить шрифт "Lucida Console"? Как я поняла нужно просто поставить шрифт "Lucida Console" для консоли и Sublime text 3.

*пробовала 1)через реестр менять значения параметров

```
*2)   #include<clocal>
      setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

*3)   std:: locale loc("Russian");
      std:: cout.imbue(loc);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939302/how-to-use-a-custom-font-in-sublimetext

Comment: При установке шрифта ошибка, пишет не является правильным шрифтом(